# OpenVPN cannot connect as client

Tags: 18.04, samba, vpn, openvpn

I installed and configured OpenVPN on my Ubuntu 18.04 machine. When I test the status of the VPN, I see that it is active but when I use the `.ovpn` file on my client and try to connect VPN, it does not connect.

What can I do and where should I look?

Client Log:

```
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] Frame=512/2048/512 mssfix-ctrl=1250
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] UNUSED OPTIONS
4 [resolv-retry] [infinite]
5 [nobind]
6 [persist-key]
7 [persist-tun]
11 [ignore-unknown-option] [block-outside-dns]
12 [verb] [3]
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:07] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:17] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:27] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:37] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:47] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] Server poll timeout, trying next remote entry...
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] EVENT: RECONNECTING ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] EVENT: RESOLVE ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] Contacting 76.158.145.102:1194 via UDP
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] EVENT: WAIT ⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] WinCommandAgent: transmitting bypass route to 76.158.145.102
{
    "host" : "76.158.145.102",
    "ipv6" : false
}

⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:21:57] Connecting to [76.158.145.102]:1194 (76.158.145.102) via UDPv4
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:22:07] EVENT: CONNECTION_TIMEOUT  BYTES_OUT : 3240
 PACKETS_OUT : 60
 CONNECTION_TIMEOUT : 1
 N_RECONNECT : 5
⏎[Sep 1, 2021, 17:22:07] EVENT: DISCONNECTED ⏎
```

Comment: Look up how to get your VPN client (not server) to emit debug output or logs. Those will tell you exactly why it's not connecting.

Comment: @user535733 I added Log can you check please

Comment: What does the client output `Server poll timeout` and `CONNECTION_TIMEOUT` suggest to you?

Comment: Do you have the proper port forwarding set up in your router to allow incoming connections to access the server?

Answer (score -1):

Reconfiguration of OpenVPN File might be the answer of your Question.

```
sudo openvpn --config whateverthename.ovpn
```